# Copying file to live VM (KVM/libvirt)

Tags: networking, ip, kvm, dhcp, libvirt

Just wondering if there is any method to copy a file to a live VM created over KVM using libvirt tools. My objective is to assign a static IP address to VM without modifying the img file or without using dhcp. What I understand is we need to have a file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ corresponding to the interface in VM where ip address has to be assigned. Wondering if I can copy this file after VM is created and booted up.

Update : I am using CentOS 7 for guest and host .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a [kickstart](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/KickStart) file for installing the machine.  That way the installer automatically sets the IP address wherever it is needed (even though you know where it needs to be set in the current version).  Copying the file onto the disk with the VM being running must be done in a way that the VM knows about that, but that means you need to have access to the machine, which, I guess, you don't; mainly since that's probably what you're trying to do.

If the machine is installed and you want to configure that without access to it and without reinstalling, I'd suggest to cleanly shutdown the VM, then use [libguestfs](http://libguestfs.org/) (mainly [guestfish](http://libguestfs.org/guestfish.1.html) command) that lets you access the disk of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

This works really well: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/9p_virtio

Basically `mkdir /tmp/share && echo '/hostshare   /tmp/share 9p  trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L   0   2' >> /etc/fstab`. On Host `mkdir /tmp/share`.

Then in Virt-manager, Add Hardware > Filesystem, change Driver to Path, add Source /tmp/share and Target /hostshare. And `mount -a`.

Or add by command `mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L hostshare /tmp/share`.